# Bootstrap navbar toggle icon and Awesome-Font icons disappearing when I upload site to server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, navbar, font-awesome, magnific-popup

Recently i uploaded my site to a server and I noticed some problems with the icons on the site.

1. On the bootstrap fixed navbar the "brand" logo and the 3 lines on the navbar toggle button disappeared.
2. I use Font-Awesome for some of my icons and they disappeared as well after uploading the site to the server.
3. Another problem i noticed is that the "Magnific-Popup" trick is not working.

I have to mention that i don't have these problem when I'm offline.

Any ideas how to solve these problems?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Usually I open the site and load Chrome's dev tools and check the console to see if there are any errors, such as 404, because it's usually a path that I missed. If it's not that, perhaps MIME, or the file(s) chmod is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first one the fix is simple. You need to change the path to the image. If the path is images/logo.png, put .. in front, so ../images/logo.png.
2. Font Awesome have a link href to it's css. You need to correct it. So,

   ```
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

became

```
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```